# What is the real age of Owen and Beru Lars?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, revenge-of-the-sith

According to the Star Wars timeline, Star Wars Episode 4: A New Hope is 20 or 19 years after Star Wars Episode 3: Revenge of the Sith, but in end of Episode 3, Owen and Beru Lars are in their 20s, but in A New Hope, they are in their 50s.

What’s with that, Owen and Beru ain’t Jedi’s.

Answer (score 1):

There are no canon sources that say when Owen and Beru were born.  However, the conditions on Tatooine are quite harsh, causing premature ageing.

In legends, Owen was born in 52 BBY and Beru was born in 45 BBY, making them around 30/23 years old in *Episode II*, and 52/45 years old when they die in *Star Wars*

Sources:  The Official Star Wars Fact File 140, *Star Wars: Episode IV*, *Star Wars: Episode II* (for the fact that Ep II occurs in 22 BBY)